# SSL handshake failure due to java update

Tags: java, ssl

My client java -version is 1.7.0_85 and the server version is lower than that. the communication takes place fine when the client was a version lower. But since the update i get the handshake_failure error. Upon firing openssl command for the server it said that the cipher was RC4-SHA in the latest update RC4 were disabled by default. Cant update the server not in my control, how should i establish the communication using properties in the java.security
 file

Comment: I'm not sure, but maybe this question should be asked at http://serverfault.com/

Answer (score 0):

You can look at the value for the `jdk.tls.disabledAlgorithms` parameter in java.security and remove RC4 from that values list.

Rather than retain this change and make clients insecure, it would be a better option if a parallel thread is opened with the server operator(s) to have them fix their SSL setup.

I'd like to repeat what the [JRE release notes](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/7u85-relnotes-2587591.html) states about the usage of RC4 (emphasis mine).

> Area: security-libs/javax.net.ssl
>
> Synopsis: Prohibit RC4 cipher suites
>
> **RC4 is now considered as a compromised cipher**. RC4 cipher suites have
>   been removed from both client and server default enabled cipher suite
>   list in Oracle JSSE implementation. These cipher suites can still be
>   enabled by SSLEngine.setEnabledCipherSuites() and
>   SSLSocket.setEnabledCipherSuites() methods.
>
> See JDK-8077110 (not public).